# Where is the datastore admin in the new Google App Engine console UI?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

This is the functionality I am referring to in the old style GAE console

[image]

At the bottom of this page, there is 'Backup Entities' button

[image]

I am not able to find the corresponding function in the new GAE console interface.

Is it possible to manually drive a backup process in the new GAE console as at the time of writing (4 Jun)?

Answer (score 1):

[Mark Cummins in the AppEngine-GoogleGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-appengine/1Qb1WEx0ukg/XeP1V06XDAAJ) has discovered that it's under Storage > Cloud Datastore > Settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing (*yet?*) in the new UI just like a lot of other features.

But you still can access it directly at `https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-APPID.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin` or even programmatically using [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups) documentation.